# How to install LawTex on MacTex

Tags: macros, mactex

I'm relatively new to LaTeX, and I run Mac OSX 10.9.1. I have the latest MacTex, and have used it with relative ease for basic documents. I'm a law student, and I'm required to make a complex document with many legal citations. I found the package  [LawTex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/?source=dlp) and from the included PDFs it's exactly what I need. However, after downloading it I have no idea how to make it work with my standard MacTex distro. Any help would be most helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you at ease with the Terminal?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am perfectly at ease with the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are acquainted with the Terminal, then it's easier.

Unzip the file you have downloaded and `cd` to the directory that is created and fix the permissions (they are wrongly set); issue the following commands starting from the directory where the ZIP file has been saved:

```
unzip lawtex-2013-06-10.zip
cd lawtex
chmod -R a+rx .
```

Now we have to create the necessary directories; I propose installing the files in the “local tree”:

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/lawtex
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/makeindex/lawtex
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/doc/latex/lawtex
```

Next we copy the files in the proper locations:

```
sudo cp *.cls bluebook.sty $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/lawtex
sudo cp *.ist $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/makeindex/lawtex
sudo cp -R *doc* samples $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/doc/latex/lawtex
```

Finish off by updating the filename database

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

Check the installation by doing

```
cd ..
kpsewhich arbitrationbrief.cls
texdoc lawtex-doc
```

The second command should output

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/lawtex/arbitrationbrief.cls
```

while the third should open the LawTeX documentation file.

---

Alternatively, you can install the files in your home; just omit all `sudo` prefixes and change all `TEXMFLOCAL` strings into `TEXMFHOME`; don't run `mktexlsr` at the end.

Comment: @kcpaige89 Good that I did try it, so discovering the wrong permissions set to the files in the ZIP file. `;-)` If LawTeX makes its way in TeX Live, remember to remove the directories that you created in `TEXMFLOCAL` and to rerun `sudo mktexlsr`. Until then, even installing a new release of MacTeX will not touch the files, that will be automatically available with the new release.

Comment: So I've recently updated my Mac to El Capitan, and from what I can tell, apparently Apple has changed how the /usr directories are accessed. @egreg , I'm wondering if there is any update I could make to get my LawTex files working again? I strangely feel like this has to do with the TEXMFLOCAL directories, but am not too sure how the underlying structure works in the Latex world.

Comment: @kcpaige89 There should be no restriction about writing in `/usr/local` and subdirectories thereof.