# LawTex on Windows 10 and Texlive 2016

Tags: texlive, windows

Please advise the steps to install LaWTex

https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/

on Texlive2016 and Windows 10 system. T

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160332/how-to-install-lawtex-on-mactex. (Note to close-voters: NOT a duplicate.) You might consider updating to TL 2017, by the way, if you want to. (2016 isn't especially old, though, but just if there's something new you want, really, or a bug fix.)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? Do you need to install it just for you or for multiple users of your system?